# How do you use OR,AND in conditionals?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have found myself many times,with things that I need to be all or at least one equal to something,and I would write something like that:

```
if a==1 and b==1:
   do something
```

or

```
if a==1 or b==1:
   do something
```

If the number of things is small its ok,but it is still not elegant.So, is there a better way for a significant number of things, to do the above?Thanks.

Comment: In this case, wouldn't you just only care if either one were just `1`? You don't need the first check, you just need the `or` check.

Comment: First one can be written `a==1==b`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Option 1: any / all**

For the general case, have a look at [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(x == 1 for x in a, b, c, d):

if any(x == 1 for x in a, b, c, d):
```

You can also use any iterable:

```
if any(x == 1 for x in states):
```

**Option 2 - chaining and in**

For your first example you can use boolean operator chaining:

```
if a == b == c == d == 1:
```

For your second example you can use `in`:

```
if 1 in states:
```

**Option 3: any/all without a predicate**

If you only care whether the value is truthy you can simplify further:

```
if any(flags):

if all(flags):
```

Comment: `1 in [a, b, c, d]` is not so great; `1 in (a, b, c, d)`.  Prefer list literals only where you need a list for the next step.

Comment: Because using a list where you could use a tuple falsely advertises an intent to do something with the list that you couldn't do with a tuple (namely, mutate an element).

Comment: tuples are quite a bit cheaper to make than lists too

Comment: Why do you say that `a==b==c==1` works only for a constant as well as `1 in a, b, c`? It works for any expression in place of `1`. And `any(iterable)`/`all(iterable)` are not going to check whether all or at least one element is non-zero, they check whether they are true.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my answer was unclear. I've tried to clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out

```
if all(x >= 2 for x in (A, B, C, D)):
```

where A,B,C,D are all variables...

Answer (score 0):

I like this form as being easy-to-understand in Python

```
def cond(t,v):
    return t == v

a=1
b=3    
tests=[(a,1),(b,2)]

print any(cond(t,v) for t,v in tests)  # eq to OR  
print all(cond(t,v) for t,v in tests)  # eq to AND
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```

Then `cond()` can be as complex as needed.

You can supply a user callable or use the [operator module](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) for more flexibility:

```
import operator

def condOP(t,v,op=operator.eq):
    return op(t,v)

a=1
b=3    
tests=[(a,1,operator.eq),(b,2,operator.gt)]

print any(condOP(*t) for t in tests)  # eq to OR  
print all(condOP(*t) for t in tests)  # eq to AND
```

Or even simpler:

```
tests=[(a,1,operator.eq),(b,2,operator.gt)]

print any(func(t,v) for t,v,func in tests)  # eq to OR  
print all(func(t,v) for t,v,func in tests)  # eq to AND
```

Comment: -0, I really hate that you return the *literal* boolean value which just had been determined in the if block.

Comment: @ch3ka: I suppose you could use another conversion that adheres to Python's sense of true and false. I like literal booleans personally. You don't? I guess you can have `return t==v` or `return op(t,v)`

Comment: @drewk personally, I prefer `if cond():` over `if cond() == True:`, and so do I prefer `return t==v` over `return True if t==v else False` - which would IMO even be more pythonic than your `if cond(): return True return False`

Comment: Verbose is not the same thing as explicit. `all(t == v for t, v in tests)` is far simpler and actually more readable.